# awk - how to add one line "TER" in .pdb file

Tags: awk, pdb

This is my fragment .pdb file:

```bash
ATOM     73  HG1 GLU     4      77.769  51.123  52.300  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     74  HG2 GLU     4      78.465  52.119  52.349  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     75  CD  GLU     4      79.068  49.945  51.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     76  OE1 GLU     4      80.069  49.715  50.698  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     77  OE2 GLU     4      78.545  49.062  52.176  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     78  C   GLU     4      81.179  52.948  53.610  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     79  O   GLU     4      80.203  53.460  54.165  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     80  N   GLU     5      82.590  53.305  53.698  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     81  HN  GLU     5      83.090  53.117  52.847  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     82  CA  GLU     5      83.454  54.267  54.627  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     83  HA  GLU     5      83.749  55.087  53.980  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     84  CB  GLU     5      82.258  54.565  55.220  1.00  0.00           C
```

I try write script in awk, which will add "TER" line directly after 4th aminoacid residue (number of aminoacid residue is given in 5th column, near three letter code of aminoacid).

My script looks like below, but it doesn't work (it doesn't add new line "TER" to pdb file in required space):

```
awk 'NR==5 {print; print "TER"} NR!=5' my_pdb.pdb > pdb-with-ter.pdb
```

Could You help me ?

I tried something like this:

```
awk 'NR==5 {print; print "TER"} NR!=5' my_pdb.pdb > pdb-with-ter.pdb
```

Finally I want obtain such fragment:

```bash
ATOM     73  HG1 GLU     4      77.769  51.123  52.300  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     74  HG2 GLU     4      78.465  52.119  52.349  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     75  CD  GLU     4      79.068  49.945  51.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     76  OE1 GLU     4      80.069  49.715  50.698  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     77  OE2 GLU     4      78.545  49.062  52.176  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     78  C   GLU     4      81.179  52.948  53.610  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     79  O   GLU     4      80.203  53.460  54.165  1.00  0.00           O
TER
ATOM     80  N   GLU     5      82.590  53.305  53.698  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     81  HN  GLU     5      83.090  53.117  52.847  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     82  CA  GLU     5      83.454  54.267  54.627  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     83  HA  GLU     5      83.749  55.087  53.980  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     84  CB  GLU     5      82.258  54.565  55.220  1.00  0.00           C
```

Comment: *after 4th id aminoacid residue* How are you supposed to detect which line is 4th aminoacid residue?

Comment: OK, I edited above fragment pdb file. Still I haven't got requirement output with TER line between 4th and 5th aminoacid residue.

Comment: While I'm familiar with `awk`, I am not familiar with `pdb`, and I have no idea what `pdb` (Python debugger?) has to do with *aminoacids* and *residues*; net result: I have no idea what you mean by *`5th aminoacid residue`*; please update the question to explain what this means in terms of the data; do all rows represent 'residue' or only some rows (and if so, which columns and values designate a `'residue')? which columns (and/or values) designate the 'nth' entry in a collection/sequence of 'residues'?

Comment: is this simply a case of inserting a row at the point where the 5th column value switches from `4` to `5`?  if 'yes' .... is the file guaranteed to already be sorted by the 5th column? or could there be multiple instances (in a single file) where the 5th column value switches from `4` to `5`? could the values switch from `4` to `6`, or `3` to `7`, and if so, do we ignore those (ie, we're looking for the exact values of `4` and `5`?)

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- when the 5th column value changes from `4` to `5`, add a new line (`TER`)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
prev==4 && $5==5 { print "TER" } 
                 { prev = $5   }
1
' my_pdb.pdb

# or as a one-liner

awk 'prev=="4" && $5=="5" {print "TER"} {prev=$5} 1' my_pdb.pdb
```

This generates:

```
ATOM     73  HG1 GLU     4      77.769  51.123  52.300  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     74  HG2 GLU     4      78.465  52.119  52.349  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     75  CD  GLU     4      79.068  49.945  51.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     76  OE1 GLU     4      80.069  49.715  50.698  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     77  OE2 GLU     4      78.545  49.062  52.176  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     78  C   GLU     4      81.179  52.948  53.610  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     79  O   GLU     4      80.203  53.460  54.165  1.00  0.00           O
TER
ATOM     80  N   GLU     5      82.590  53.305  53.698  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     81  HN  GLU     5      83.090  53.117  52.847  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     82  CA  GLU     5      83.454  54.267  54.627  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     83  HA  GLU     5      83.749  55.087  53.980  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     84  CB  GLU     5      82.258  54.565  55.220  1.00  0.00           C
```

Comment: @skywalker just change `$5==5` to `$5!=prev` if you want TER added after 4 regardless of what the next number is. You don't need quotes around the numbers in the comparisons btw.

Comment: OK,It works. But, I want add a new line (TER), when the 6th column value changes from 5 to 6. I modify above your code as below:
awk 'prev==5 && $6!=prev {print "TER"} {prev=$6} 1' my_pdb.pdb but It doesn't work.

Comment: @skywalker the original question mentions the 5th column's value changing from `4` to `5`;  you're now stating you want to apply similar logic for the 6th column; assuming you're dealing with the same data set (as provided in the question) ... the 6th column does not contain any values equal to the integers `5` nor `6` so I wouldn't expect your code to add any new lines;  the answers you've received are geared towards your original question ... if you're having problems applying these answers to a new problem then I'd suggest you ask a new question